# [Ocaml]: Build lexer.mll

Tags: emacs, ocaml, interpreter

I use Ocaml by installing OcamlWinPlus and its component Emacs. In my source I have two file main.ml and lexer.mll with following code:

main.ml:

```
open Format

let print data =
  List.iter (fun l -> printf "%s@." (String.concat " " l)) data
let () = 
  match List.tl (Array.to_list Sys.argv) with
  | [filename] -> 
      let ch = open_in filename in
      let data = Lexer.lex [] (Lexing.from_channel ch) in
      close_in ch;
      print data
  | _ -> eprintf "killer <file>@."; exit 1
```

lexer.mll

```
rule lex xs = parse
  | [' '  '\r' '\t']     { lex xs lexbuf }
  | '\n'                 { List.rev xs :: lex [] lexbuf }
  | ['0'-'9']+ as x      { lex (x :: xs) lexbuf }
  | eof                  { [] }
```

there is a trouble when I run Ocaml in emacs:

```
Error: Unbound module Lexer
```

Please help me fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You failed to describe what you tried here... I guess that you did not compile `Lexer` before compiling `main.ml`, though it depends on `Lexer`. What you should do is:

- Convert `lexer.mll` to `lexer.ml` with `ocamllex`: `ocamllex lexer.mll`
- Compile `lexer.ml`: `ocamlc lexer.ml`
- Then compile `main.ml`

To automate this process, you should use some build tool such as `make`, `ocamlbuild`, `omake`, etc. In any case, you should read a good OCaml introductory book to learn how to use OCaml and its tools with multi source files.

Comment: When I compile main.ml, I got another error:
File "main.ml", line 1:
Error: Error while linking main.cmo:
Reference to undefined global `Lexer'

Comment: `ocamlc -c main.ml`, then `ocamlc -o your.exe lexer.cmo main.cmo`. PLEASE READ THE MANUAL!

Comment: Thank you, I built my source by this way: 
ocamlc -c lexer.ml
ocamlc -c main.ml
ocamlc -o taka lexer.ml main.ml
ocamlrun taka

Comment: Thank you so much. I can build my source code by your way. Can you recommend me a good book to learn Ocaml language.